# How can I save an image by PHP?

Tags: php, avatar

I have a script which generates an image. I have used it like this so far:

```
<img src='/img/avatar/identicon.php?size=35&hash=64d134jf23tgr7k' height='40' width='40'>
```

Now I'm trying to store it as a image in this path:

```
/img/avatar/$id.jpg
```

And then use it like this:

```
<img src='/img/avatar/$id.jpg' height='40' width='40'>
```

How can I store that image as a real image in a folder?

**Note:** I have `id` as a dynamic variable, and I want to use it as the name of image.

Comment: firstly, variables don't get parsed in single quotes `'/img/avatar/$id.jpg'` so you need to use double quotes `"/img/avatar/$id.jpg"` but you mention to store it. Just do; there are a few functions for that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ah, good point about quotes. Thank you. And may you please introduce me a function for that?

Comment: Instead of returning the raw image data, you could use [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) with it's 2nd parameter beforehand. Another option would be RewriteRules for apache.

Comment: You're welcome. There's `move_uploaded_file()` and `file_get_contents() / file_put_contents()` and `fwrite()`. @stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to save the image first, here's one way to do it:

```
$id = "someID.jpg";
file_put_contents("img/avatar/".$id, file_get_contents("http://somesite/img/avatar/identicon.php?size=35&hash=64d134jf23tgr7k"));
```

then use it like this:

```
<img src='/img/avatar/<?=$id?>' height='40' width='40'>
```

Comment: Copy is another way, it's up to you ;)

Comment: In your code, what's the path of output? I mean where that image will sore?

Comment: The image will be stored in the path you choose

Comment: In this case, in the relative path `img/avatar/`